# Async function called recursively returns undefined to the callee function

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, async-await

I have an async function being called from an another async-lock code. The asyn function makes an API call which is critical and hence I need to use retry logic to try to execute it twice. After running twice it should break.

My code implementation breaks the recursion properly but problem is before the second async function can execute the called method inside async lock is getting an undefined response therefore breaking the lock. The response from the second API call is happening outside the lock. The code is as follows:

```
 //Callee function:
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               lock.acquire('Block_key', () => {
                if(shouldRefresh()){
                    return getApiCall(
                        config, 
                        flow,
                        retryCount
                    )
                    .then((response) =>  {
                        //debugger;
                        // Getting a undefined response
                        return resolve('Generated Success');
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {                           
                        return reject(err);
                    })
                } else{
                    global.logger.info(`Returned from Cache.`);
                    // Remove cannot log token
                    global.logger.info(JSON.stringify(result));
                    return resolve(result);
                }
               },opts).then((response) => {
                    //debugger;
                    return resolve(response);
               })
               .catch((err) => {
                return reject(err);
               })
            });

//Recursive Async function
        const getApiCall = async function(config,flow, retryCount){
            const hrstart = process.hrtime();
            try{
                let result =  await _ouath2.getToken(util.getTokenConfig(config, flow,_scope)); // making the API call                    
                let newResult = util.adjustExpiration(result, _refreshBufferTime);
                _token = _ouath2.token.create(newResult);
                return _token;
            } catch(err){                                   
                if(retryCount === 1){ // hreaking the recursion
                    _log('Failed enough... Quitting now');
                    return err;
                }else{
                    setTimeout(() => {                            
                        getApiCall(config,flow, retryCount-1); // making the recursive call
                    }, 3000)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not a recursive function - you aren't returning anything in the else. What you want to do is `return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(getApiCall(...)),3000))`. Quickly typed pseudo-code, no guarantees there aren't syntax errors. :)

Comment: @Adam: Whoaa.. It worked. But it still appears magic to me why was it returning an undefined earlier? I understand I should have returned something in the else block. Where am I going wrong conceptually?

Comment: If you don't return anything and you just call the function in a setTimeout, then the function that called `getApiCall` had no idea it needed to wait any longer, as far as it was concerned, `getApiCall` was done and returned `undefined`. Does that help?

Comment: Understood and makes sense. However, if I always resolve the response from getApiCall the function calling it gets a resolved promise and never gets an error. Thus it always gets into the  .then((response) =>  {
                        //debugger;
                        // Getting a undefined response
                        return resolve('Generated Success');
                    }) even if I actually get an error. I tried doing a .then and resolve reject from the call but I end up getting an unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

Comment: Basically I am trying to do the below: 
                if(retryCount === 1){
                    throw err;
                }else{
                     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {                            
                            getTokenApiCall(tokenConfig,flow,count-1).then((res) => {
                                return resolve(res);
                            }).catch((err) => {
                                throw err;
                            })                              
                        }, 1000)

Comment: My bad fixed it now. Had to reject the err. :). Thanks for all the help. You are a rockstar. If you have some page/profile lemme know if I can hook onto it.  @Adam

Comment: The original code I proposed would've worked fine, but the problem was you were returning the error from `getApiCall` in the if(retryCount === 1) - what you needed to do was change the `return err` to `throw err` and that was all. Can't quite tell from what you did if that's the only change you made. If you always `resolve` with `getApiCall(...)` - then that's fine as long as `getApiCall` `throw`'s the error and doesn't just return it.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong as @Adam pointed out in the comments was not returning anything while making the call in the recursive block. Note, the response from an async function can only be a promise hence, the call to the function was made within a new promise block and resolved/rejected. This sent a proper response instead of an undefined response.The correct code is:

if(retryCount === 1){
                    throw err; // important to throw an error here
                }else{
                     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            getApiCall(config,flow, retryCount-1).then((response) => {
                                return resolve(response);
                            }).catch((err) => {
                                global.logger.info('Error'+err);
                                return reject(err);
                            })
                        }, 1000)
                    }) 
                }